# Usar argparse para leer y usar valores de un json

Tags: python, test, argparse, unittest

Me pidieron realizar una estructura de pruebas en la que por medio de argparse se pudiera leer la configuración de un json y usar dichos datos para determinar el flujo de pruebas. Basicamente que si yo escribo python prueba.py -c -Dev dicha prueba se ejecute usando chrome en google.com(EJEMPLO). En la función browser_choice ya se logró que mediante comando se mande el navegador deseado para la prueba, pero en enviroment_choice cuando mando el comando prueba.py -c -Prod me manda el siguiente error. temp = Test.test_company1(parsed_args)
AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'test_company1'
Este es mi archivo JSON

```
{
  "Configuraciones": {
    "Browser": {
      "c": "chrome",
      "f": "firefox"
    },
    "Enviroment": {
      "Dev": "https://www.google.com/",
      "Uat": "https://es.stackoverflow.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Y este es código de prueba.

```
import json
import argparse
import unittest
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def get_data():   
        with open('services.json') as conf:
            data = json.load(conf)
            return data

    def browser_choice(data, playwrights):
        atts = vars(parsed_args)
        if atts ["chrome"]==True:
            browser = playwrights.chromium.launch(headless=False)

        elif atts ["firefox"]==True:
            
            browser = playwrights.firefox.launch(headless=False) 
        return browser

    def enviroment_choice(args):
        if args == "-Prod":
            url = "http://localhost:3000/organigrama/miempresa-edit"
            print ("Produccion")
        else:
            print("Test")
        return url

    def test_company(parsed_args):
        

        with sync_playwright() as playwrights:
            
            browser = Test.browser_choice(parsed_args, playwrights)
            print("Bienvenida")
            page = browser.new_page()
            url = Test.enviroment_choice("-Prod")
            page.goto(url)
            browser.close()   
            

if __name__ =="__main__":  
    data = Test.get_data()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Escoge un navegador")
    parser.add_argument("-c","--chrome",action="store_true",dest="chrome",help="Navegador Chrome")
    parser.add_argument("-f","--firefox",action="store_true",dest="firefox",help="Navegador Firefox")
    parser.add_argument("-e","--edge",action="store_true",dest="edge",help="Navegador edge")
    parser.add_argument("-Prod",action="store_true",dest="Producción",help="Ambiente de producción")
    parser.add_argument("-Test",action="store_true",dest="Test",help="Ambiente de testing")
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
    print(parsed_args)
    temp = Test.test_company1(parsed_args)  
    #Test.browser_config(parsed_args)
    #data = Test._data(parsed_args)
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu pregunta está incompleta, por lo que está respuesta también lo sera.

No necesitas el módulo Unit Test, pues te piden una aplicación, no pruebas unitarias (son otra cosa).

Al configurar las opciones tienes que indicar un campo de destino en el parámetro `dest=:

```
parser.add_argument("-c", "--chrome", action="store_true", dest="chrome", help="Navegador Chrome")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--firefox", action="store_true", dest="firefox", help="Navegador Firefox")
```

Luego de parsear los argumentos con

```
parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
```

tienes dos campos booleanos que te dicen que opciones se seleccionaron:

```
parsed_args.chrome
parsed_args.firefox
```

Con esto ya puedo abrir el archivo de configuración y ejecutar el proceso:

```
with open('services.json') as conf:
    data = json.load(conf)
    with sync_playwright() as playwrights:
        if parsed_args.chrome:
            browser = playwrights.chromium.launch(channel="chrome", headless=False)
        else:
            browser = None  # Sustituir por browswer firefox

        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("http://localhost:3000/organigrama/miempresa-edit")
        browser.close()
```

Según el browser elegido, se instancia Chrome o Firefox y se ejecuta contra la página.

Nota: La especificación de los parámetros te permite elegir '-c', '-f, ambos o ninguno. Sin embargo, en el código mostrado sólo se pide una página via sólo un navegador.

#### Código

La posible solución (no probada por falta de detalles) es

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Escoge un navegador")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--chrome", action="store_true", dest="chrome", help="Navegador Chrome")
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--firefox", action="store_true", dest="firefox", help="Navegador Firefox")
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
    with open('services.json') as conf:
        data = json.load(conf)
        with sync_playwright() as playwrights:
            if parsed_args.chrome:
                browser = playwrights.chromium.launch(channel="chrome", headless=False)
            else:
                browser = None  # Sustituir por browswer firefox

            page = browser.new_page()
            page.goto("http://localhost:3000/organigrama/miempresa-edit")
            browser.close()
```